# Почему не получается запустить программу на node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, visual-studio-code

Сам node.js скачан, через командную строку работает, но в VSC выдаётся ошибка: https://i.stack.imgur.com/COKDB.png

Comment: Перезапускать редактор пробовали?

Comment: Получилось, спасибо!!! (не сарказм)

Comment: Хотя может перезагрузка ноута тут помогла